# Which wire is positive on this audio jack (blue and white)?

Tags: wiring, polarity, plug

[image]

Which wire is positive and which is negative on an audio jack wire that I have cut off to do some experimental work? I have searched the internet and a lot of answers contradict each other.

Comment: The wires are copper (a guess only) and the copper is the same in both wires. The signals between the wires may have polarity. Audio signals are AC but the polarities may still be defined for ex. to prevent out of phase left and right stereo speakers or microphones in multi-microphone recording system.  We know nothing what's expected in the other end of the cable. If there's nothing, but the same looking wire ends, the problem is solved as soon as you connect the cable. BTW we do not know if there's more conductors in the cable than the shown 2 wires.

Comment: don't be thinking that insulation color means something ... the manufacturer chooses any color they like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Audio does not have a positive and negative as the signal is alternating in voltage. If it is an audio cable it will usually have a signal wire and a shield wire. These can easily be identified by measuring the resistance between the poles of the plug and the bare wire ends.

Comment: right, sorry for my mistake :) . So it does not have polarity at all and can connect it anyhow :)

Comment: No, for audio there is usually a screen to shield the signal wire and the shield surrounds the signal wire. Your photo doesn't show that or the connector at the other end so we can't be sure. The shield is connected to the barrel of the jack and to the circuit ground.

Answer (score 3):

Audio is AC.  The wires can't be separated into positive and negative.

One of the two will, however, be "ground."

You would have to show both ends of the cable for someone to explain how to determine which wire is ground.